# Why does my installer not run while using the /norestart flag?

Tags: operating-system, windows-installer, exe, installshield, silent

I am going for a silent installation for one of my msi exe. The goal is to get the installer to run silently. I understand and know how to run it silently. The task at hand is that when I run it silently the OS restarts. So I implemented an additional flag to take care of the restart along with my silent flags. Below is the command I run for silent and no restart.

```
JumpyJackGame.exe /s /v/qn /norestart
```

The problem I am running into is the .exe does not even run when I add the /norestart command

Answer (score 1):

What project type are you using? And do you use a Suite project (essentially a bundle of several setups delivered as a single setup.exe) or just a regular project wrapped in a normal setup.exe launcher?

See the official help for these different setup.exe types:

- [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm)
- [Advanced UI and Suite/Advanced UI Setup.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteSetupexeParam.htm)

If you use a regular Basic MSI (which you should for its standards compliance), then you might be able to do this:

```
Setup.exe /s /v"/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
```

See more samples in the documentation. The **`REBOOT=ReallySuppress`** should stop rebooting from "normal causes". A custom action designed to do so may still be able to force-restart the system, but that is terrible design if implemented in such a manner (it should register the need to reboot only).

I will add a link in the morning - when I get time - to a previous answer on the different setup.exe types.